# add primary key to mapped super class inherited entity JPA

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance

I am trying to create my database with JPA and i have a mapped super class "user" from wich the entities "student" and "teacher" inherit (they extend from the mapped super class) and the "chief" entity extends from "teacher" but the primary key of "chief" has another column.
How can I add a column to the primary key using JPA annotations.

Comment: all objects in an inheritance tree have to have the same PK. You can't add extra fields further down the tree. Assuming this was your question ...

Comment: @Neil Thanks, yes this was my question. But can i use unique constraints or anything to make the columns like PKs ?